# How to find the indefinite integral for a natural log being divided by x?

Tags: integration, logarithms

I've done many examples in the math book but none of them have a natural log as a numerator. Here's the question.

$$\int\frac{(\ln\ x)^7}{x} dx$$

I am given these 2 properties, where $u$ is a function.

$$\int\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln|\ x\ |+C$$

$$\int\frac{u'}{u}du = \ln|\ u\ |+C$$

Comment: Start again, substitution, $u=\ln x$.  And don't forget the $dx$ in your integrals.

Comment: I know that $ln\ x$ is the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$, but I would need to make the denominator of x be $\frac{1}{x}$ in order for u' to be $ln\ x$.

Comment: The derivative of $\ln x$ is $\frac{1}{x}$, the previous comment has it the other way around.

Comment: ... how did you get from $\int\frac{\ln^7x}{x}dx$ to $7\int\frac{\ln x}{x}dx$ which is equal to $\int \frac{\ln(x^7)}{x}$?

Comment: is $\int\frac{(ln\ x)^7}{x}$ or $\int\frac{ln\ x^7}{x}$

Comment: log property. Bringing the exponent down and then taking the constant out of the integral.

Comment: Brief solution, maybe not using the notation of your course. Let $u=\ln x$. Then $du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ and our integral is $\int u^7\,du$. Now it's almost over.

Comment: actually $\log(x^7) = 7 \log(x)$ but $(\log(x))^7 \neq 7 \log(x)$

Comment: It is very important that you check your question, and in particular make sure that the parentheses in your function are in the same place as in the book's question. You at least partly misquoted, the book probably did not leave out the $dx$.

Comment: I just fixed it.

Comment: there are some pretty good hints above.... I would suggest, you try those. And you may find the solution yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because my book had no example like this at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the substitution $u=\ln x$. This gives us $\mathrm{d}u= \dfrac1x \ \mathrm{d}x$. Replacing $\dfrac1x \ \mathrm{d}x$ with $\mathrm{d}u$ gives us $$\int\! u^7 \ \mathrm{d}u=\frac{u^8}{8}+C$$ Back substituting $\ln x=u$ $$\frac{(\ln x)^8}{8}+C$$

Comment: Why that one downvote?

Comment: It is hard to diagnose at a distance. Maybe a toothache.

Answer (score 2):

by using the by parts method
$$\int\frac{(\ln\ x)^7}{x} dx=(\ln x)^7.\ln x-7\int\frac{(\ln\ x)^7}{x} dx+C$$
$$8\int\frac{(\ln\ x)^7}{x} dx=(\ln x)^8+C$$
$$\int\frac{(\ln\ x)^7}{x} dx=\frac{(\ln x)^8}{8}+K$$